# Seperating Amazon and Android metrics in Google Analytics SDK

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk, amazon-fire-tv

We're using the Google Analytics SDK in our Android and Fire TV app. Since both are Android based, the metrics get reported together. However, I'd like to have the metrics for Android and Amazon devices reported separately.

I do see where we are able to view User Engagement by Screen Class, but that doesn't provide me any of the real metrics I'm looking at like User numbers and Session times.

Is there a way to filter the views in Google Analytics so that I can see the data by each of those platforms? What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After some additional digging, I was able to filter out for Amazon by device model numbers. Here is a device listing with model numbers from Amazon:

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/identify-amazon-fire-tv-devices.html